# Contractor installed HVAC before permit was approved. How normal is that?

Tags: hvac, permitting

A pretty well known local company installed me a mini split system, and only after they finished the job and I was about to invite the inspector, I noticed the permit is not approved yet. In fact, they did not attach plans and I have to beg them to do that so the permit could go through. I did pay them to get the permit and they attached me a receipt as a proof they have it (now I understand it was only a proof they submitted an unfinished application).

They are very slow to respond and I'm not 100% sure if it's going to be approved (who knows if they satisfied all the requirements).

Is it a severe violation? Should I sue them if anything goes wrong with the permit? Am I overreacting?

Comment: After the work is done and they're paid, they have no reason to prioritize your request.

Comment: It should be okay for something as simple and common as a mini split.  I would be more mad at the permit office for taking so long for a simple rubber stamp.

Comment: The permit office rejected them immediately because they did not attach any plans (I see that in the history on the permit office website)

Comment: Then go after the company for the cost of the permit and doing unpermited work.  I thought it was the office holding up getting the permit to you.

Comment: My heat pump replacement was done and "inspected" a couple weeks after.  The county guy seemed to indicate that this was pretty common, if not *de rigeur.*  My assumption is that they don't want to hold up installations to wait for permit approval when people are without heat or cooling (depending on season).

Answer (score 5):

The contract for the work included getting the permit. It's their responsibility.

Do not give final payment if the permit is not approved and all inspections are done and signed off.

Some local inspectors know and trust the contractors that do quality work and allow some wiggle room around the rules.

Yes you are overreacting a bit. There are no "permit police"  They won't come and take you to jail.   At the most possibly a fine ( locally it about $40.00) and the contractor should pay that.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that the job was financed through them, so I don't have an option to hold off the payment (without dealing with the bank, I guess)

Comment: I can confirm this - I've had electrical work done more than once with no inspection visit, just a valid and completed permit. In both cases it was a well known local electrical company. I assume they get spot-checked.

Comment: Deal with the bank, then. They should not, **under any circumstances**, be paid in full until you have a signed off final inspection.